# ng-bootstrap radio buttons are only data flowing one-way

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

My [radio buttons](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/buttons/examples) are flowing data only one-way. Changing the model sets the correct radio button active, but changing the radio button doesn't flow the data back up.

I'm also not sure why there's a difference in the example between `[value]` and `value` as there doesn't appear to be any explanation given for the difference.
 [Here's a Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/a4ASHpSdyJtyCSI22rws?p=preview) that works which I've tried to mimic exactly in my code, but it's still not working. This app isn't far from the base angular-cli app, and I've commented out any jQuery or Bootstrap JavaScript files but I'm thinking there still may be some kind of conflict preventing data from flowing back up. Other non-ng-bootstrap `[(ngModel)]` bindings **are** working fine however.

What's also odd is that if in Augury I change the character in the component's `selection.character` model, the radio button updates appropriately. But selections aren't updating the model.

**Here's my template code**

```
<div [(ngModel)]="selections.character" ngbRadioGroup name="radioBasic">
            <label ngbButtonLabel class="btn f3 ba b--light-silver">
              <input ngbButton type="radio" value="Bugs"> Bugs
            </label>
            <label ngbButtonLabel class="btn f3 ba b--light-silver">
              <input ngbButton type="radio" value="Porky"> Porky
            </label>
            <label ngbButtonLabel class="btn f3 ba b--light-silver">
              <input ngbButton type="radio" value="Daffy"> Daffy
            </label>
</div>
```

**component.ts**

```
//sample default selections
selections = {
  character: "Bugs",
  anotherField: null,
}
```

Comment: Could you explain how you know that it's not binded, I mean how do you check? I tried to make a plunker with your code and it seems working.

Comment: I have a spot where I'm just spitting out the value, and it shows the initial value, but clicked the radio button doesn't change it.

Comment: Like {{selection.character}} ?

Comment: Yes, exactly like that.

Comment: @redOctober13 I've copied your example into a sample plunker and it works perfectly fine for me: http://plnkr.co/edit/SrXII7oZG07YxRWWw26U?p=preview. Could you try to reproduce the issue by modifying this plunker? Otherwise it is hard / impossible to help. Also `value="ConstantValue"` vs. `[value]="expression"` is more of the Angular thing that anything specific to ng-bootstrap.

Comment: I had a Plnkr linked to as well, and it works, which is why this is confusing. I'll try with an `ng new` app. As to the `value` thing, the ng-bootstrap's site users both on their example. I think it has something to do with string values?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. I haven't been using a barebones `ng new` app, but something that was rolled together internally, which included a packaging of the bootstrap JavaScript file, and that was causing the conflict that was preventing data from flowing back up.

So, if you're using `ng-bootstrap`, make sure you don't also have the plain bootstrap JS files being imported, referenced from CDN, etc. Probably beyond obvious to some people, but it wasn't even mentioned on the ng-bootstrap site.